# A bounded non-constant holomorphic function on the set $\{z \in C\mid|z|>1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

What is an example of a bounded non-constant holomorphic function on the
set $\{z \in C\mid|z|>1\}$?

Comment: What about $1/z$?

Comment: More generally, $f(z) = g(1/z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic and bounded in the unit disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the non-constant functions

$f_n(z) = \dfrac{1}{z^n} = z^{-n}; \tag 1$

they are clearly holomorphic, and

$\vert f_n(z) \vert = \left \vert \dfrac{1}{z^n} \right \vert < 1 \tag 2$

for

$\vert z \vert > 1; \tag 3$

thus each $f_n(z)$ provides an example of such a function.